# Why does this code throw a NullReferenceException when adding strings to listbox from a text file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, text, listbox

Here's the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Initialize Array to hold student names
    new string[] names = { "David Palladini", "Michael Reyes", "Bram Lesser", "Hans Herrmann", "Nathan Texeira" };

    //Initialize Array to hold student evaluations
    new double[,] evaluation = { {1.0, 0.8, 0.9 ,1.0,0.6},
                                 {0.2, 0.9, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7},
                                 {0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 0.9},
                                 {0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0, 1.0},
                                 {1.0, 0.9, 1.0, 0.8, 0.9} };


    public Form1()
    {
        StreamWriter outputFile;
        outputFile = File.CreateText("names.txt");

        foreach (string name in names)
        {
            outputFile.WriteLine(name);
        }

        outputFile.Close();

        string studentName;
        StreamReader inputFile;
        inputFile = File.OpenText("names.txt");

        while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            //Reads name from text file
            studentName = inputFile.ReadLine();

            //Writes name to listbox
            nameListBox.Items.Add(studentName);
        }

        inputFile.Close();

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

The evaluation array is irrelevant for now. I'm trying to display all the names in the names array into a listbox immediately upon launch. I also know that writing them into a text file and then reading them from it is a very roundabout way of doing things, but in this situation I have to.

The problem is that it throws a NullReferenceException error right here:

```
        //Writes name to listbox
        nameListBox.Items.Add(studentName);
```

For the life of me I can't figure out why. Is the original array not being written into the text file correctly? Or am I doing something wrong when trying to read back the strings?

Comment: make sure `nameListBox` exists and is initialized, and make sure `studentName` exists and has data in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe `nameListBox` will exist before calling `InitializeComponent();` Try moving that line to the top of the Form1 constructor.

Comment: WOW that was an easy fix. Thank you! Can you explain why that would be exactly? My understanding was that I could write the conditions for starting the form and then {InitializeComponent():} would initialize it under those constraints. I guess it still technically does that but I have to put that method first?

Comment: When you build the form in the IDE (Visual Studio etc), the code to build and configure those objects is generated by calling the `InitializeComponent();` method. You can still see your objects in intellisense before calling the initialize method because they have been declared but you cannot work with them because they have not been assigned a value.

Answer (score 1):

Try move your initialize to the top:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    StreamWriter outputFile;
    outputFile = File.CreateText("names.txt");

    foreach (string name in names)
    {
        outputFile.WriteLine(name);
    }

    outputFile.Close();

    string studentName;
    StreamReader inputFile;
    inputFile = File.OpenText("names.txt");

    while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
    {
        //Reads name from text file
        studentName = inputFile.ReadLine();

        //Writes name to listbox
        nameListBox.Items.Add(studentName);
    }

    inputFile.Close();


}
```